# Formula to calculate pokemon go evolutions

Tags: excel, pokemon-go

I am trying to write a simple excel formula to calculate the number of evolutions I can make based on my candy and number of pokemon. I am trying to maximize XP, so I am only trying to evolve any given pokemon once. For some reason I couldnt find this in a brief google search. This was what I came up with, anyone have any suggestions, either to simplify the formula or account for some pokemon go quirk I failed to notice?

```
=IF(min(floor((candy_have+pokemon_have-1)/candy_to_evolve),pokemon_have)<0,0,min(floor((candy_have+pokemon_have-1)/candy_to_evolve),pokemon_have))
```

Basically this says:

- add candy + unevolved pokemon and divide by the number of candy required to evolve the pokemon
- round down to an integer value
- if the value is less than 0 round up to 0

Comment: There's a plethora of equations on https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev/. Might just have to do a little searching.